# Getting "can't create user databases on a --configsvr instance" error while trying to start replicaset of config server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, configserver

I want to create a replicaset of confiserver. For that I performed the following steps:
 1. I created two config server using the following configs:

```
sharding:
 clusterRole: configsvr

replication:
 replSetName: TestConfigServer1

net:
 bindIp: 127.0.0.1
 port: 27018

storage:
 dbPath: E:\Programming\MongoDBProgramming\Mongodb
```

---

```
sharding:
 clusterRole: configsvr

replication:
 replSetName: TestConfigServer1

net:
 bindIp: 127.0.0.1
 port: 27019

storage:
 dbPath: E:\Programming\MongoDBProgramming\Mongodb1
```

2. Then I connected "mongo" to the first config, and ran following commands:

```
rs.initiate()
rs.add( {_id: 1,host: 127.0.0.1:27019} )
```

This created the replicaset with 27018 port as primary.

Then after closing all the mongod servers, I tried to start the replicaset again.

I started the port 27018 first using the corresponding config file, and then I tried started port 27019 the same way. For the 27019 I got the following error:

> 2020-05-20T21:48:37.449+0530 F  -        [replication-0] Fatal assertion 40088 InitialSyncFailure: error cloning databases :: caused by :: Location14037: Error cloning collection '.new_enrollment' :: caused by :: can't create user databases on a --configsvr instance at src\mongo\db\repl\replication_coordinator_impl.cpp 743

Also, when connected mongo shell to the 27018 server, and checked the replicaset status, then it showed the 27018 server as secondary.
What am I doing wrong here?

---

Edit: Result from rs.status()

```
TestConfigServer1:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "TestConfigServer1",
        "date" : ISODate("2020-05-20T17:03:47.950Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "term" : NumberLong(4),
        "syncingTo" : "",
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "configsvr" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1589991517, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(4)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1589991517, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(4)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-05-20T16:18:37.962Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2020-05-20T16:18:37.962Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1589907661, 1),
        "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : Timestamp(1589907661, 1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 3168,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1589991517, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(4)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-05-20T16:18:37Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                        "configVersion" : 2,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27019",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-05-20T17:03:46.549Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2020-05-20T16:18:37.166Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(7),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27019 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.",
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : -1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000004")
        },
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1589991517, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1589991517, 1)
}
```

Comment: What do you get from `rs.status()`?

Comment: Did you try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Added the status.

Comment: Tried localhost also, but got same error.

Comment: Did you have a look at your log files?

Comment: Did you check the status after `rs.initiate()` before you run `rs.add()`? Ensure that the data directories are empty when you initialize the server.

Comment: No I did not check status after rs.initiate(). For server 27019, which is supposed to be secondary, I emptied the database directory, but still got the same error, while starting it.

Comment: What about the directory of the primary? It must be also empty.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Primary still contains full database.

Comment: I think then you should follow the [Convert a Replica Set to a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/). In case your existing database is a stand-alone DB then you must [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) beforehand

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you started the first config server in a data directory that was previously used for another deployment. Start with an empty data directory.

Comment: Yesterday, I ran the config server on the database path. Today I am facing this problem. So whenever I restart my server, do I have to create new database?

Comment: No but you do need to keep the directories for each mongod instance separate and use each one appropriately. A name like `E:\Programming\MongoDBProgramming\Mongodb` doesn't tell you *what* is in that directory.

Comment: It is separated, one is in Mongodb1 directory and the other in Mongodb.

Comment: I gave different path for the 27019 server DB, but still got the same error.

Comment: "new_enrollment" is a database you created at some point, yes?

Comment: No, it is a collection.

Comment: I don't think you can create a collection before you added the first shard. Of course, shards can be added only after initialization. Looks like you executed commands in wrong order. Stick stricktly to the order given in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/index.html

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I already had a databse, I was trying to create shards for that.